# AWS - Share resource between multiple accounts through single VPCE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

Scenario: We have multiple accounts (A,B and C) in the organization.
Account A have a resource/service for which access is granted through single VPCE from Account B.
Account C also need access to this resource but have to go through Account B only.

Have anyone faced this peculiar situation? if yes, how could we allow traffic from Account C through Account B for a specific port there by utilizing the VPCE on B to access the resource on Account A.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "access is granted through single VPCE"? What type of VPC Endpoint is this? Is it currently working? Or are you referring to VPC Peering, or perhaps PrivateLink? What is the purple icon in the middle?

Comment: Its an interface endpoint and there is no VPC peering enabled. Probably just firewall  need to be open channel between Accounts C and B.  Account B to A, we have the private link.